# OpenCV convertTo()

Tags: c++, opencv

I came across this code:

```
image.convertTo(temp_image,CV_16SC3);
```

I saw the description of the convertTo() function from [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#mat-convertto), but what confuses me is `image`. How can we read the above code? What would be the relation between `image` and `temp_image`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is a **source**, the second one - **destination**. So, it takes image, converts it into type CV_16SC3 and stores in temp_image.

Answer (score 11):

The other answers here are correct, but lack some details. Let me try.

```
image.convertTo(temp_image,CV_16SC3);
```

You have a *source* image `image`, and a *destination* image `temp_image`. You didn't specify the type of `image`, but probably is `CV_8UC3` or `CV_32FC3`, i.e. a 3 channel image (since `convertTo` doesn't change the number of channels), where each channel has depth 8 bit (`unsigned char`, CV_**8U**C3) or 32 bit (`float`, CV_**32F**C3).

This line of code will change the depth of each channel, so that `temp_image` has each channel of depth 16 bit (`short`). Specifically it's a `signed short`, since the type specifier has the *S*: CV_16**S**C3.

Note that if you are narrowing down the depth, as in the case from `float` to `signed short`, then `saturate_cast` will make sure that all the values in `temp_image` will be in the correct range, i.e. in [–32768, 32767] for `signed short`.

**Why you need to change the depth of an image?**

1. Some OpenCV functions require input images with a specific depth.
2. You need a matrix to contain a different range of values. E.g. if you need to sum (or subtract) some images CV_8UC3 (tipically BGR images), you'd better store the result in a CV_16SC3 or you'll probably get wrong results due to saturations, since the range for CV_8U images is in [0,255]
3. You read with `imread`, or want to store with `imwrite` images with 16bit depth. This are usually used (AFAIK) in medical or graphics application to allow a wider range of colors. However, most monitors do not support 16bit image visualization.
4. There may be other cases, let me know if I miss the one important to you.

Comment: Saving this answer! Awesome

Answer (score 2):

An image is a matrix of pixel information (i.e. a `1080p` image will be a `1,920 × 1,080` matrix where each entry contains `rbg` values for that pixel). All you are doing is reformatting that matrix (each pixel entry, iteratively) into a new type (`CV_16SC3`) so it can be read by different programs.

The `temp_image` is a new matrix of pixel information based off of `image` formatted into `CV_16SC3`.

Comment: @Miki, ah yes my bad, updating